# How do I restore a Postgres database from within a SQL query?

Tags: postgresql

When in development, I need to clean down my system by restoring a database backup and then running SQL against it. Is there a way to do this:

```
restore schema dbo 'c:/data/mydatabase.backup';
update dbo."MyTable" set "ColumnA" = 1;
```

Unlike other questions, this is **not** for doing via the command line but in a query instead.

Postgres v9.5 with pgAdminIII.

Comment: No, there is no such SQL statement. The only way is to do it via command line (either with `psql` or `pg_restore`)

Comment: Thank you, would you care to make that an answer? So I can close off the question for anyone else landing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support to restore a dump from within a SQL statement in Postgres.

---

Some possible (ugly) workarounds:

If your dump is a SQL script you could theoretically run that script from wherever you would run that (hypothetical) restore statement - but that would require parsing the script. And you would need to generate the dump using the `--inserts` option as otherwise the script contains `psql` specific statements.

Another workaround could be to create a stored function in a un-trusted language that is able to run operating system commands. The actual restore would still be done by the command line utility, but you could *initiate* that from within SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the ugly workarounds. I'm going to go into Powershell instead!